# Scientific reasons for not eating certain animals?

Tags: food, animals, scientific-proof

Muslims are not allowed to eat certain animals like pig, dog etc. but are allowed to eat cow, chicken, lamb etc.

I don't understand the reason behind this refraining from eating some animals but are allowed to eat others. **If eating meat is the issue, Allah should have commanded us to remain vegetarians!**

Is there any scientific explanation for not eating certain animals?

Some say that pigs eat filthy things and the meat is not healthy for consumption. However, if the pig is reared in a clean environment, won't it make it a clean animal?

Comment: I'm not aware of any studies that compare the consumption of different kinds of meat with each other, you should ask the people on [health.se] about that. Just looking at studies that say "consuming pork in X amounts has Y negative correlates" doesn't tell you anything since you would need to compare pork to halal foods that have negative effects. For anthropological ideas and historical background about how it came about that pork was forbidden in the Middle East, see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_restrictions_on_the_consumption_of_pork) and follow the leads from there.

Answer (score 2):

I think it may also be because animals such as cattle, sheep, goats, buffalo, deer and camels, etc are ruminant animals; meaning they have 4 stomachs... Whereas pigs aren't and only have one stomach. Therefore ruminant animals digest their food over a 24hr period and during the digestive process, they get rid of excess toxins as well as other components of the food eaten that could be dangerous to health. But as a pig only has 1 stomach and digests it's food in about 4hrs, many of these toxins remain in their system to be stored in their more than adequate fatty tissues ready for human consumption.

Also as the pig's body system is so much like the human system, many diseases are transferable between pigs and humans, more so than any other animal.

Comment: Then what about carnivorous animals like lion etc.?

Comment: That's a similar argument for kosher food

Answer (score 0):

This question have been asked to Ja`far ibn Muḥammad al-Ṣādiq (Arabic: جعفر بن محمد الصادق‎)(I will translate the important parts):

> محمد بن يعقوب ، عن عدة من اصحابنا ، عن سهل بن زياد ، وعن علي بن ابراهيم ، عن أبيه جميعا ، عن عمرو بن عثمان ، عن محمد بن عبد الله ، عن بعض اصحابنا ، عن أبي عبد الله ( عليه السلام ) ، وعن عدة من اصحابنا ، عن أحمد بن محمد بن خالد ، عن محمد بن مسلم  ، عن عبد الرحمان بن سالم ، عن مفضل بن عمر ، قال : قلت لابي عبد الله ( عليه السلام ) : اخبرني ـ جعلني الله فداك ـ لم حرم الله الخمر والميتة والدم ولحم الخنزير ؟ قال : ان الله تبارك وتعالى لم يحرم ذلك علىعباده واحل لهم ما سواه  من رغبة منه فيما ( حرم عليهم )  ، ولا زهد فيما ( احل لهم )  ، ولكنه خلق الخلق ، ( فعلم )  ما تقوم به ابدانهم ، وما يصلحهم ، فأحلّه لهم واباحه ، تفضلا منه عليهم به لمصلحتهم ، وعلم ما يضرهم فنهاهم عنه وحرمه عليهم ، ثم اباحه للمضطر ، واحله له في الوقت الذي لا  يقوم بدنه الا به ، فامره ان ينال منه بقدر البلغة لا غير ذلك ، ثم قال : اما الميتة فانه لا يدمنها  احد الا ضعف بدنه ، ونحل جسمه  ، ووهنت قوته ، وانقطع نسله ، ولا يموت آكل الميتة الا فجأة ، واما الدم فانه يورث اكله الماء الاصفر ، ( ويبخر الفم ، وينتن الريح ، ويسيء الخلق )  ، ويورث الكلب ، والقسوة في القلب ، وقلة الرأفة والرحمة ، حتى لا يؤمن ان يقتل ولده ووالديه ، ولا يؤمن على حميمه ، ولا يؤمن على من يصحبه ، واما لحم الخنزير فان الله تبارك وتعالى مسخ قوما في صور شتى مثل الخنزير والقرد والدب ، ( وما كان من المسوخ )  ثم نهى عن اكله للمثلة لكيلا ينتفع الناس ( به ، ولا يستخفوا بعقوبته )  ، واما الخمر فانه حرمها لفعلها وفسادها ، وقال : مدمن الخمر كعابد وثن يورثه الارتعاش ، ويذهب بنوره ، ويهدم مروءته ، ويحمله على ان يجسر على المحارم من سفك الدماء ، وركوب الزنا ، ولا يؤمن اذا سكر ان يثب على حرمه وهو لا يعقل ذلك ، والخمر لا يزداد شاربها الا كل شر
>
> > I asked Abi Abd Allah (a.s): tell me why did Allah forbid wine, dead animals, blood and pork?
> >     He said: Allah (swt) didn't forbid things and allow others because of his desire in what he forbade [...] but because he created the creations and knew what is *better for their  health so he allowed it and knew what is bad for their health so he forbade it* [...] and he forbade pork because Allah (swt) metamorphose a group of people in various forms such as pig, monkey and the bear and then forbade eating it...

From this we conclude that some of these animals have organs that are identical to the organs of humans and thus we can't eat them as we can't eat the meat of a human being.[Here is a comparison between the organs of humans and pigs.](http://www.goshen.edu/bio/pigbook/humanpigcomparison.html)

> the swine immune system is the closest to the human one in the animal kingdom. Deseases can therefore be shared between pigs and humans much easier than any other animal.

In addition, no one can ignore the [harm that pork can do to your health](http://www.miraclesofthequran.com/scientific_72.html) even from a [scientific point of view](http://articles.mercola.com/sites/articles/archive/2012/12/12/eating-pork.aspx).

From a spiritual point of view, [You are what you eat](http://dujs.dartmouth.edu/fall-2010/you-are-what-you-eat-how-food-affects-your-mood) and if we observe the traits of these animals we can see really bad traits that islam discourages and even fights.

Comment: Wife of animals? I don't think so something like that exists. Besides its just not pig that let that, almost all animals let their wives sleep with others, simply because there is no marriage and wives in animals.

Comment: I have edited that out.

Comment: @AshwinSingh this is not true, many animals have marriage. for example, bulls and cocks try to guard their wives from other males.

Answer (score -1):

Muslim are allowed to eat the animals like cow , goat , hen , sheep etc who eat the grass and other tree etc 
We are not allowed to eat the meat of such animals who eats the meat of animals like dog eats the dead smelly animals, Pork also takes the Bad Smelly Food etc due to this food intake pork dogs and other prohibited animals blood and meat becomes Dirty .

Islam is 100% natural religon.

Comment: There are cows in Indian Cities like Delhi, who eat garbage near the road. Are they still clean?

Comment: are they eat the Dead animals ?

Comment: Possible, because there are also dead animals in the garbage. Anyway, a pig in a clean pig-farm is fed only hygienic foods. If, I never allow my pigs eat any dirty things and give them almost the same food that I'm eating, doesn't it make them healthy enough?

Comment: Pig are Prohibited Also in Quran as well thats the biggest reason than the Health .

Comment: and For Your info Cow Can not eat meat ...

Comment: So, you mean the prohibition is not exactly for health issues but more to do with spirituality and obedience to Allah? Because I believe that obedience to Allah is the most important thing for a Muslim.

Comment: I have mentioned the Health issues before mentioning that its prohibited in ISLAM
Pork is not eatable meat for our health because it has too dangerous germs in the meat which cannot be destroyed by much heat also. So don't think that we cooked and it is germ free.

Answer (score -3):

Oddly, almost all animals that're regarded as haram are either near extinction, or have some form of emotional attachment to humans. Take for example dogs and cats, or horses, or whales, or elephants, or eagles etc..